# Cannot Use Raspberry Pi Camera v1/2 with Gumstix Pi Compute Dev Board

Tags: raspberry-pi, gumstix

Referencing this item:

https://store.gumstix.com/gumstix-pi-compute-dev-board.html

I cannot use the official Pi camera(s) using either the official Raspberry Pi "Buster" disk image or the Pi disk image provided by Gumstix:

Disk image referenced here--> https://store.gumstix.com/raspberry-pi-cm-fast-flash.html

Note:  The Gumstix Pi image would "hang" on the rainbow colored splash screen during boot, using the image above. I am using the "fast flash" board to write the images, and have been able to repeatedly (successfully) install the standard Raspbian OS. FYI I have been using Balena Etcher, and it has worked with my other boards.

Also, I followed the official instructions to add camera support in an attempt to understand what I am doing wrong. **vcgencmd** initially reported no support or detection in raspbian. I was able to add camera support using the blobs mentioned here (I compliled manually and also used the precompiled variant):

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/cmio-camera.md

Final result:

vcgencmd get_camera : supported=1 detected=0

Lastly, yes the camera is enabled, and I have tested the cam/cable on other systems with no issues. I suspect the pin GPIO settings may be to blame, but based on the information in front of me (for this board) I should not be expecting to manually adjust those params. Thanks for any insight….hopefully this is an I-D-10-T error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off I should appologize, the page you referenced about getting the disk image is very out of date.  We will work to update it soon.

My guess of why it's not booting is likely a hardware imcompatibilty, are you using a Raspberry Pi CM3+?

Give this image a try

https://gumstix-raspbian.s3.amazonaws.com/2019-12-29/raspberrypi-cm3/rpi-4.19.y/2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-lite.img.xz

That's a recently compiled Buster image that has some extra drivers added in to support Geppetto modules.  The default Buster image should also work.

To properly support any of our boards, it's best to download the board support package for that particular design.  In your case, you're using the Gumstix Pi Compute Dev Board, which can be found

https://geppetto.gumstix.com/#!/design/1045/

Please go to that page and click on the "AutoBSP" button on the top.  That will prompt you to download a zip file that will contain some instructions and files needed to configure the Raspberry Pi.

Please let me know if you have any trouble.

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: I was able to successfully setup and use the camera per the instructions above. I started by downloading the dev board's BSP linked above, then followed the instructions in the readme included in the BSP package. The only deviation I took from the readme was flashing the "2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-lite.img.xz" image versus the "stretch" image mentioned. Running "vcgencmd get_camera" listed support & detection for my camera. I also successfully took a sample photo. The software support package/BSP is well documented and worked perfectly, just need an update to the product page!